# How to fill a binary outcome to all rows within a group in dplyr?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `group_by()` to create a new variable that assigns either a 1 or 0 based on a condition (two criteria). I'd like to assign 1 to ALL rows within the group if the condition is met ONCE, and a 0 if not at all. The code below assigns the 1 at the single line in which the condition is met. How can I adjust this to fill all rows within the grouping variables?

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("Group1", "Group2"), each = 18),
  d_num = rep(c(1:6), times = 2, each = 3),
  var1 = sample(1:4, 36, replace = TRUE),
  var2 = sample(1:4, 36, replace = TRUE)
)

x <- dat %>%
  group_by(group, d_num) %>%
  mutate(var3 = ifelse(var1 == 1 | var2 == 1, 1, 0))
```

Comment: `var3 = max(ifelse(var1 == 1 | var2 == 1, 1, 0))`

Comment: What do you want to happen if the condition is met more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your condition in `any()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- dat %>%
  group_by(group, d_num) %>%
  mutate(var3 = ifelse(any(var1 == 1 | var2 == 1), 1, 0))
  
print(x, n = 20)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 36 × 5
# Groups:   group, d_num [12]
   group  d_num  var1  var2  var3
   <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 Group1     1     3     2     1
 2 Group1     1     1     1     1
 3 Group1     1     2     2     1
 4 Group1     2     4     1     1
 5 Group1     2     4     3     1
 6 Group1     2     3     2     1
 7 Group1     3     4     2     1
 8 Group1     3     2     2     1
 9 Group1     3     3     1     1
10 Group1     4     3     4     1
11 Group1     4     3     1     1
12 Group1     4     4     2     1
13 Group1     5     3     4     0
14 Group1     5     3     3     0
15 Group1     5     2     2     0
16 Group1     6     3     3     0
17 Group1     6     2     2     0
18 Group1     6     2     4     0
19 Group2     1     4     3     1
20 Group2     1     1     3     1
# … with 16 more rows
```